# openssl s_client losing connection after each request

Tags: get, openssl, request, client, keep-alive

I'm playing around with openssl s_client and a webserver and I wonder why I'm losing the connection to the server after each GET request I send:

Handshake works fine:

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname:port
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname
Connection: keep-alive
```

Then I receive the response from the application server:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

```
...more http here...
<html/>closed
```

As you see the connection is closed, but as I used the connection header with keep-alive, isn't the connection supposed to stay established? I want to test the renegotiation feature of SSL and therefor I need to be able to keep the session alive between several requests.

Comment: does your webserver send the keepalive header as well?

Comment: In the response it is stated:

   'Connection: close'

So that means that my server is not supporting the keep-alive on its side?

Comment: i guess it doesnt support the keepalive without configuration changes on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server must reply with a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header as well to establish a keepalive connection.

Change your server side configuration to do this.

But be aware of the performace issues coming with keepalive connection as well as the fact that many browsers close the connection after a certain timeout.